# Could not find an option named "web-server-debug-protocol" when running a Flutter project through VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-problem-matcher

I am using VSCode ad my Flutter development IDE. It worked well until this afternoon. When I ran the project, `Could not find an option named "web-server-debug-protocol"`showed up. I have no idea what goes wrong.
I googled "web-server-debug-protocol" and only found two links showed that it exists in the flutter_command.dart.
Did anyone meet the similar problem? Any suggestions about that?
Thanks!

[image]

**UPDATE**
I solved this issue by upgrading my Flutter.

Comment: what version did you used? mine is `3.10.1` but still got the error

Comment: Flutter 1.19.0-1.0.pre

Comment: Restart VsCode, if its not working then check you channel and change it to stable and upgrade the stable version to latest and then try

Comment: That happened to me, when I had two project opened in VS Code - one from Beta channel, other from Stable. Reopening VS Code fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

echo.

**I reinstalled Flutter extension in VS Code and it worked properly.**

good flutter life!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reinstalled Flutter extension too in the beginning, but it didn't work for me. I ended up upgrading Flutter then it works.

Answer (score 5):

For me restarting the VS Code did the Job.

Answer (score 3):

Just restart VS code. It often happens when you switch between Flutter channels, but restart should fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just upgraded Flutter and it works.